# Glide won't load in image

Tags: android, android-glide

See below. The photo loads in originally but Glide won't load it back upon going back into the Settings Activity.

Initially when the user selects an image to go into the ImageView, 
The image goes in and is saved to my Firebase storage and the
URL is passed to the database. Here is the code:

```
if(map.get("profileImageUrl")!=null){
    profileImageUrl = map.get("profileImageUrl").toString();
    Glide.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(profileImageUrl).into(mProfileImage);
}
```

Comment: figured out the issue though i dont know how to resolve. I was getting the upload url, though the download url is not "gettable" from taskSnapshot.

Comment: Please check first what value holds profileImageUrl using  Log or debug your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I had imported the wrong version of the file Glide from GitHub. I went and got it from there and my App worked perfect.